# Angular2, TypeError: el.toLowerCase is not a function in Autocomplete Process

Tags: autocomplete, angular

When I am try to integrate autocomplete in angular2, I got TypeError i.e
   el.toLowerCase is not a function.

```
filter() {
if (this.query !== ""){
    this.filteredList = this.names.filter(function(el){
        return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    }.bind(this));
}else{
    this.filteredList = [];
 }
}
```

Comment: Did this code come from [AngularTutorial](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html)? Having the same issue

Answer (score 18):

Try `return el.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;`. If the argument `el` is not a string, the `toLowerCase()` function won't work on it.

Comment: Thanks.  My syntax is different but nevertheless calling .toString() fixed the error.  This is probably thrown when el is undefined, and the .toString() function forces it to be an empty string value.

Comment: In my case, the variable was an array object defined as 'string' (not 'String') and using toString() before toLowerCase() solved the problem. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.. Its working for me..

```
filter(event: any) {
    if (this.query != "") {
        this.FilteredApplicationNames = this.ApplicationNames.filter(function (el) {
            return el.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }.bind(this));
    } else {
        this.FilteredApplicationNames = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
return !input || (el ? ('' + el).toLowerCase().indexOf(input) !== -1 : false);
```

This works because the object `el` is cast to a string using `'' + el`. Since it's now a string object, we can use the `toLowerCase()` function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

Try `this.el.toLowerCase()`. If the argument `el` being passed in is a property of the class, it might not recognize it without `this.` in front of it. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm currenty using the same code, [Source](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html), and `this.` didn't do the job

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, hope you figure it out